# Excel: Populate Data Across Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Unfortunately for my employer, none of my network engineering courses included advanced Excel formula programming. Needless to say, I know nothing about Excel save for basic SUM and COUNT formula commands.

My employer has an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets within it representing each month of the calendar year. We want to be able to have a "total" worksheet in the workbook that reflects all data across the entire workbook in each column/row.

An example for the sake of clarity:

- In the worksheet "May_2013", column A is labeled "DATE". Cell A2 contains the data "MAY-1".
- In the worksheet "June_2013", column A is labeled "DATE". Cell A2 contains the data "JUNE-1".
- In the worksheet "Total", column A is labeled "DATE". We want cells A2 to reflect "MAY-1" and A3 to reflect "JUNE-1".

We want to do this for all worksheets, columns A-Q, rows 2-33 and populate a master sheet at the very end containing all data in all worksheets in their corresponding columns.

Is this possible?

Comment: Reading more carefully (after posting a quick bit of code) I am not sure what you intend to do with row 3 of the May worksheet. I assumed it would be copied to row 3 of the summary sheet, but now I see you want to put row 2 of JUNE there. How is the data from the other rows treated? Can you please clarify?

Comment: So far I've come up with a solution, but it is insanely tedious and time-consuming, although the results are what I'm looking for. Someone recommended I enter the following: '=SheetName!Cell' for every corresponding cell on the Totals sheet. This is a crazy amount of work, but it does what I want it to do, which is merge all of the data on all of the spreadsheets in the workbook to the totals sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two VBA solutions. The first does this:

1. Check if a sheet "totals" exists. Create it if it does not
2. Copy the first row (A to Q) of first sheet to "totals"
3. Copy block A2:Q33 to "totals" sheet starting at row 2
4. Repeat for all other sheets, appending 32 rows lower each time

The second shows how to do some manipulation of the column data before copying: for each column it applies the `WorksheetFunction.Sum()`, but you could replace that with any other aggregating function that you would like to use. It then copies the result (one row per sheet) to the "totals" sheet.

Both solutions are in the workbook you can download [from this site](http://www.floris.us/SO/summarize.xlsm). Run the macros with , and pick the appropriate one from the list of options that shows up. You can edit the code by invoking the VBA editor with .

```
Sub aggregateRaw()
Dim thisSheet, newSheet As Worksheet
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim targetRange As Range

sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

' add a new sheet at the end:
If Not worksheetExists("totals") Then
  Set newSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(sheetCount))
  newSheet.Name = "totals"
Else
  Set newSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("totals")
End If

Set targetRange = newSheet.[A1]

' if you want to clear the sheet before copying data, uncomment this line:
' newSheet.UsedRange.Delete

' assuming you want to copy the headers, and that they are the same
' on all sheets, you can copy them to the "totals" sheet like this:
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("1:1").Copy targetRange

Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(1, 0) ' down a row
' copy blocks of data from A2 to Q33 into the "totals" sheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.Name <> newSheet.Name Then
    ws.Range("A2", "Q33").Copy targetRange
    Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(32, 0) ' down 32 rows
  End If
Next ws

End Sub

Sub aggregateTotal()
Dim thisSheet, newSheet As Worksheet
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim columnToSum As Range

sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

' add a new sheet at the end:
If Not worksheetExists("totals") Then
  Set newSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(sheetCount))
  newSheet.Name = "totals"
Else
  Set newSheet = Sheets("totals")
End If

' assuming you want to copy the headers, and that they are the same
' on all sheets, you can copy them to the "totals" sheet like this:
Set targetRange = newSheet.[A1]
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Q1").Copy targetRange

Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(1, 0) ' down a row

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  ' don't copy data from "total" sheet to "total" sheet...
  If ws.Name <> newSheet.Name Then
    ' copy the month label
    ws.[A2].Copy targetRange

    ' get the sum of the coluns:
    Set columnToSum = ws.[B2:B33]
    For colNum = 2 To 17 ' B to Q
      targetRange.Offset(0, colNum - 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(columnToSum.Offset(0, colNum - 2))
    Next colNum
    Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(1, 0) ' next row in output
  End If

Next ws

End Sub

Function worksheetExists(wsName)
' adapted from http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/3228-visual-basic-applications-check-if-worksheet-exists.html
worksheetExists = False
On Error Resume Next
worksheetExists = (Sheets(wsName).Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**Final(?) edit:**
If you want this script to run automatically every time someone makes a change to the workbook, you can capture the `SheetChange` event by adding code to the workbook.  You do this as follows:

1. open the Visual Basic editor ()
2. In the project explorer (left hand side of the screen), expand the VBAProject
3. Right-click on "ThisWorkbook", and select "View Code"
4. In the window that opens, copy/paste the following lines of code:

`Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
' handle errors gracefully:
On Error GoTo errorHandler

' turn off screen updating - no annoying "flashing"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' don't respond to events while we are updating:
Application.EnableEvents = False

' run the same sub as before:
aggregateRaw

' turn screen updating on again:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' turn event handling on again:
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub ' if we encountered no errors, we are now done.

errorHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
' you could add other code here... for example by uncommenting the next two lines
' MsgBox "Something is wrong ... " & Err.Description
' Err.Clear

End Sub`

Comment: Where do I enter this VB script? And will it merge all data on all spreadsheets into a master totals sheet?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but looking at your code it seems as if it does some arithmetic. What I want I think is a bit simpler than that. I just want all of the data on all of the sheets in the workbook appear on a totals page.

Comment: It was not clear from the question if you wanted totals or just all the raw data - especially since you said you wanted A3 to have "June" in it. I gave two options - the first copies all data, the second takes totals. And yes, you open VBA editor , insert module, paste code. Let me know if you need more info to get this working.

Comment: To help you out, I have created a dummy file with a couple of sheets of data, and with a working version of both the above macros in it. You can download it from [this location](http://www.floris.us/SO/summarize.xlsm). Run macro with <Alt-F8>, look at code with <Atl-F11>. You will see two functions - `aggregateRaw` and `aggregateTotal`, corresponding approximately to each of the above. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: You can copy your sheets into the dummy workbook and delete the sheets that are currently there, then save it under a new name (with `.xlsm` extension to enable the macros). That should solve it for you.

Comment: My apologies for my lack of clarity. I ran your script and it did everything I wanted it to do, but when I edit a cell on the other worksheets it doesn't update the totals sheet, and when I attempt to run the script again to update it, it returns a runtime error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No worries about "lack of clarity" - it can be hard to describe these things, which is why we use comments to clarify. What "runtime error" message did you get? Do you get the opportunity to "debug" ? - it would show you the line with the error. The requirement to update automatically was never spelled out in your question...

Comment: By the way - did you run the script as it is showing currently (the most recent edit was happening while you were writing your comment...). I did fix a small problem in the code in the last 15 minutes... newest version is at same link as before.

Comment: In the first iteration of your code which I tried, it worked perfectly the first time I ran it. The second time (to update it as it did not do this automatically) returned "Run time error: 1004   Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: The newest line of code again works like a charm! Is there a way to continuously run this script automatically?

Comment: I have edited my answer - follow the instructions to make the script run every time you change the sheet. Side effect is that if you manually edit the "totals" sheet, your edit will be undone (since original data will overwrite it when the script runs).

Comment: Should I be applying this to the Workbook in VB or the Totals sheet?

Comment: Your comment was truncated; I can't see your error. The new script needs to go in the workbook code (that way it will trap the event regardless of the sheet that caused it).

Comment: When I run this script, I get this error:

"Compile error: Sub or function not defined" and it highlights this line: "Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)"

Comment: I am puzzled. Are you trying to run the `SheetChange` thing? You don't need to run anything. Every time you change something in your workbook, the totals will automatically update. You don't have to "run" anything now. Just in case, I have re-uploaded a version that was working on my computer a couple of minutes ago (with two sheets of dummy data) to the same link as above. Just enter data and watch the magic...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize. The whole script works extremely well. Only issue is that it removes all of my headers at the top of the totals worksheet. Can we keep my headers intact and add the info below the very first row on the worksheet? All other worksheets have the exact same headers. If we can get the headers working, this is a complete lifesaver and exactly what I need. Thanks so much for your attention and help.

Comment: In `Module1`, find the lines `' if you want to clear the sheet before copying data, uncomment this line: ' newSheet.UsedRange.Delete ' assuming you want to copy the headers, and that they are the same ' on all sheets, you can copy them to the "totals" sheet like this: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("1:1").Copy targetRange` . If you comment out that line (by putting an apostrophe `'` in front of it), your problem should go away? A similar line exists in the `aggregateTotal` function but I think you're not using that anyway. When you confirm it's OK, you might consider "accepting" the answer...

Comment: Thanks. Got the headers going. The information doesn't seem to be updating when a cell on one of the other spreadsheets is changed. Is there a way to get the totals sheet to update on the instant a cell in the workbook is edited?

Comment: I wonder if something you did triggered an error, so you are left in a state where event processing was disabled. Try two things: first, close Excel and open it again - does that help? Second, add a new sub to Module1 with just three lines: `Sub reStart() Application.EnableEvents=True End Sub`. Run that macro. See if things get better. Let me know.

Comment: Closed Excel and reopened with current iteration of code to no avail. Added the posted line Sub reStart() Application.EnableEvents=True End Sub again to no avail. Is there a setting I need to enable to allow macros to continuously loop?

Comment: The macro doesn't "continuously loop" - it captures a specific event (SheetChange), and updates the totals sheet when that happens. Make sure File-->Options-->Trust Center-->Macro Settings-->"Enable all macros" is enabled. I am assuming you are running a recent version of Excel?

Comment: It was the specified setting in Excel. Thank you so much for your time and patience with an Excel noobie. I actually learned a lot with this. I greatly appreciate your persistence and assistance with this issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help. Glad you learnt something  - we all started somewhere, and had someone to help us....

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use RDBMerge add-in which will combine the data from different worksheet and create a master sheet for you. Please see the below link for more details.

http://duggisjobstechnicalstuff.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-merge-all-excel-worksheets-with.html

[Download RDBMerge](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm)

Comment: There is no way to do this without add-on software?

Comment: @Brandon Its an excel add-in. Once you refer the addin to your workbook its like plug n play. Ofcourse these can be achieved without this addin.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the add-in. I see where it allows me to merge all of the data in each corresponding column, but I do not see where I can define an output column or worksheet for that data.

Comment: @Brandon the output would be on worksheet in which you are running the addin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indirect function to reference the sheet name.  In the image below this function takes the header name (B37) and uses it as the sheet reference.  All you have to do is choose the correct "total cell" which I made "A1" in "MAY_2013".  I put an image below to show you my reference name as well as tab name

[image: Formula]

Comment: It returns an invalid cell reference error. What cells should I be referencing here?

Comment: the first reference should be a cell with the exact tab name.  the second reference should be the cell location in the referenced tab that has the value you wish to return.  If you did this manually it would look like `=MAY_2013!A1`

Comment: That is precisely what I want to do, but will I need to enter this formula into each and every cell on the totals sheet? The totals sheet needs to contain all data on all sheets within the workbook, so that's a whole lot of editing. Is there a way to populate the cells with this information in a more streamlined way? Is there a way to define a range? Something like =May_2013!A1:A35 (this doesn't work, but just as an example).

Comment: in your spreadsheets you may have a total in "A1" and if that location is the same for all sheets then it will work.  Otherwise you can have a named range for those values on each sheet but then you wouldn't need indirect.

Comment: Each and every spreadsheet in the workbook has the exact same table setup with the exact same categories, including the totals sheet. There is actually no other formulas anywhere in the workbook. It's pretty simple other than this totals sheet I'm trying to create. What would be the correct formula syntax to set up a range so I don't have to put a separate formula in each and every cell?

Comment: Try this `=SUM(INDIRECT(INDIRECT("B35")&"!A1:A35"))`  It will sum up that specific range for whatever header you have as long as the header matches a tab.

Comment: Trying to test this formula: What is the "B35" in reference to again? Here's how I'm entering it: '=SUM(May_2013(May_2013("B35")&"!A1:A35"))' Returns an error of "Invalid name error". I'm thinking this is in reference to the B35.

Comment: B35 is the cell that has the tab name in it, A1:A35 is the range you want to sum in the tab which has the same name as the cell B35.  You need to use the `INDIRECT` function for it to work

Comment: The tab as in the worksheet? Or the tab as in the column category in the May_2013 worksheet? I have data being used as a column category called "Last" for last names in cell E1. If I want to copy the range of all last names, would I be doing this -- '=SUM(INDIRECT(INDIRECT("E1")&"!E2:E35"))'

Comment: I typed "=SUM(INDIRECT(INDIRECT("May_2013")&"!E2:E35"))" (May_2013 is a worksheet within the workbook), and it returned "Invalid cell reference".